# Can RFI be radiated by connector wire even if shunted at opening?

Tags: rf, noise, emi-filtering

Imagine a metal enclosure with an XLR connector. My understanding is that it is vitally important for pin 1 of the XLR (the shield) to be connected to the chassis with a very short conductor to make the shield (and connector shell) part of the chassis and shield everything from RFI. For just this reason, Neutrik connectors (like NC3FAV1) often have a little metal spike in one of the screw holes to make contact with the chassis. This is connected to pin 1 so that RFI is shunted into the chassis over what is only maybe 1-2 cm of metal.

The question is, if there is something connected to pin 1 like a long PCB trace, even if RF is shunted into the chassis as described above, can the presence of this trace still emit RF noise?

Similarly, if pin 1 was not shunted by said spike, and there was an *unterminated* PCB trace, could it emit EMI? (Not that I would do this, I'm just trying to understand how HF noise is radiated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in a fairly subtle way on exactly where that trace connects relative to where the chassis bond is connected.

If things connect in a 'T' configuration then there is a common impedance due to the length of one of the Ts arms, and that will develop a voltage when RF flows which will appear between your internal trace and the chassis. 
2cm is a quarter wavelength at ~3.7Ghz and will appear as a high impedance at this frequency, it will still have significant reactance down into the cell phone and wifi bands. 
If on the other hand the connection is physically Pin1--Chassis bond--internal net then there is no problem.

Your floating trace looks like a ground plane antenna at some frequency and will couple rf picked up on the cable screen outside the box to the inside of the box.

Best practise is to tie pin 1 very directly to the chassis, use a common mode choke and caps on the signal pair and connect your internal single ended reference plane to chassis at one point ensuring no common impedance coupling.

Jim Brown wrote the book on this stuff, see http://audiosystemsgroup.com/AES-RFMicrophonesASGWeb.pdf for a paper including some pictures of how not to do it.

Comment: It is also worthwhile to pay special attention to any screws used to form this chassis bond.  Avoid "galvanic corrosion" caused by "dissimilar metals" (google these terms if you are not familiar with them).  Your chassis may be aluminium but most screws are steel.  Such corrosion can reduce an electrical connection's conductivity over time (several years).  If you have the option to use soldering or welding to make a solid connection to the chassis then this is ideal.

Comment: Should the signal wires have a choke, then caps or caps then choke? The mic cable has some inductance so would it be better to do caps then choke so that you have cable inductance -> cap -> choke -> input capacitance to make a two pole. Or should it just be cable inductance -> choke -> cap -> input capacitance to make a bigger one pole?

Comment: The reason I ask is because if the caps are first they can be very close to the pins whereas if the choke is first, then the traces have to be significantly longer to make it back to the caps on pin 1. And I figure the 100p caps are probably doing more by themselves than the choke?

Comment: For a mic pre I would have a good look at the app notes from THAT Corp, their RFI network is not bad (I usually add a small SMT CM choke, a 1206 sized affair, but whatever), and they have useful things to say about the hazards of P48 when combined with a short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

If this is always a low impedance ground track, the question becomes what current and spectrum is nearby that can be coupling to this inductive track?

The ratio of the coupling impedance (f) to track impedance (f) will varying with unintended radiator frequency,

If it is unknown what spectrum of noise exists inside, then it cannot be determined if it will harm or not.